# ACF в WP (прайс лист)

Tags: wordpress, acf

Надо на странице реализовать прайс лист. 20 моделей, в каждой модели по 30 строк. Сайт на WP. Решил использовать ACF. Создал 20 групп полей под каждую модель. Подключил на страницу и тут появилась ерунда какая-то. До 11 модели все было хорошо - данные вводил, они запоминались и выводились на сайте. Но с 12 модели, группу полей выводятся на странице, в админке, я заполняю группу контентом, нажимаю "Обновить", чтобы сохранить страницу, а весь контент по позиции 12 не сохраняется, как вообщем и последующий. Такое ощущение что существует некий лимит сохраняемых данных. Бред какой-то. Можете кто-то подсказать как быть?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: Это не болезнь php, а всего лишь настройка. Создавать 1000 полей ввода на одной странице  - неправильно. Вам нужно выбрать иной способ решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ  KAGG Design. Да, это болезнь PHP, интернет этой проблемой завален. Нужно исправит показать max_input_vars в php.ini

Comment: Но лучше подумайте с чем у вас глобальная проблема и перестройте так, чтобы добавив еще 10 моделей не сломалась ваша чудо штука)